# Chromium does not show certificates from ~/.pki/nssdb

Tags: chromium

I installed the latest stable Chromium (`79.0.3945.117`) through `apt` on Ubuntu 19.10.

I have some `mtls` certificates in `~/.pki/nssdb`, that show up in Google Chrome (same version) under "Your certificates" on `chrome://settings/certificates`, but don't show up in Chromium.

I can manually export certificates from Chrome and import them in Chromium. When I then delete them from `~/.pki/nssdb`, they are gone in Chrome, but the imported cert is still there in Chromium. The documentation says

> Chromium does not have an SSL certificate manager. It relies on the NSS Shared DB `~/.pki.nssdb`

But it looks like it's not. I have no idea what it's using for a certificate store and I don't know where to start debugging. Is there a setting I'm missing? How can I get chromium to use the correct nssdb?

Comment: Chromium for 19.10 is a snap, thus reads the files located within the containerized snap itself (with limited access to your real file-system unless you enable `snap connect` options to enable access).  I'm not sure a *connect* option exists for what you want sorry.  It's been used for 7+ months now so I'd anticipate it's been noticed before so I'd look at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-chromium-browser-deb-to-snap-transition in your place.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the problem. Looks like people are aware, but it doesn't seem to be an issue for anyone. I tried replacing `~/snap/chromium/current/.pki` with a symlink to `~/.pki`, but the certs still don't show up (also, I think the symlink will get replaced with the next update)

Comment: I would post on the community (discourse) site I mentioned;  oSoMoN (Olivier) still monitors it & will likely request a bug report (*if one hasn't already been filed for it*).  The launchpad bug report will be the most useful spot however I didn't search there, thus didn't mention it.

Comment: Yep, did that and they immediately filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1859643